# Improving a region plot

Tags: plotting, regions

I have two surfaces which I plot them using

```
p0 = Plot3D[{2  x Cos[y] + 2 x Sinh[y], -2  x Cos[y] - 
    2 x Sinh[y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 7}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Green, Opacity[0.5]], 
    Directive[Green, Opacity[0.5]]}, PlotPoints -> 25
    , Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {0, 7}, {-1.0, 1.0}}]
```

To fill the region between these two surfaces, I use

```
p1 = RegionPlot3D[{2  x Cos[y] + 2 x Sinh[y] + v < 0 , 
   2  x Cos[y] + 2 x Sinh[y] - v < 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 7}, {v, -1, 
   1},  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[1.25]], 
    Directive[Yellow, Opacity[1.25]]}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
    Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Mesh -> None]
p2 = RegionPlot3D[{2  x Cos[y] + 2 x Sinh[y] - v > 0 , 
   2  x Cos[y] + 2 x Sinh[y] + v > 0}, {x, -1, 0}, {y, 0, 7}, {v, -1, 
   1},  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[1.25]], 
    Directive[Yellow, Opacity[1.25]]}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
    Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Mesh -> None]
```

Finally, I plot all of them together using

```
Show[p0, p1, p2, PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {0, 7}, {-1.0, 1.0}}, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

The outcome looks like
[image]
While this script fulfills my initial inquiry, I am not fully happy with the plane at `x=0`, which is there because of having separated regions `p1,p2`.
Do you have a suggestion on improving this figure and removing the line at `x=0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found another way to do this which only use `Plot3D`, the keypoint is using `Filling`.

```
Clear[g, plot1, plot2];
g[x_, y_] = 2 x Cos[y] + 2 x Sinh[y];
plot1 = Plot3D[{g[x, y], -g[x, y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 7}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 7}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   ClippingStyle -> None, Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Yellow, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}];
plot2 = Plot3D[{g[x, y], -g[x, y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 7}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 7}, {-1, 0}}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
   ClippingStyle -> None, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Yellow, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}];
Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this.

```
Clear[g];
g[x_, y_] = 2 x Cos[y] + 2 x Sinh[y];
p0 = Plot3D[{g[x, y], -g[x, y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 7}, 
   ClippingStyle -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Green, Opacity[0.5]], 
     Directive[Green, Opacity[0.5]]}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 0.5}, {0, 7}, {-1.0, 1.0}}];
plot = RegionPlot3D[{-v <= g[x, y] <= v , v <= g[x, y] <= -v}, {x, -1,
     1}, {y, 0, 7}, {v, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[1]], 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}];
Show[p0, plot]
```

[image]